# work group barrier not working

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencl, gpu

as a simple test to see whether or not the OpenCL 2.0 functions work for me, I've written a small kernel that calls work_group_barrier.  However, for the life if me, I can't figure out why the kernel becomes invalid.
Considering that the kernel will be valid if "barrier" is used, and work_group_barrier is just a renamed version of barrier, this doesn't make sense.

The kernel in question:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_printf : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_subgroups : enable

//pragmas go here
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

__kernel void my_dumb_test(

__global float *in0, 
__global float *in1, 
__global float *out
){

int global_num = get_global_id(0);
int local_num = get_local_id(0);
int local_size = get_local_size(0);
int global_size = get_global_size(0);
int group_id = get_group_id(0);
int group_num = get_num_groups(0);
local int a;    
int b = 2;
//a = work_group_broadcast(b, local_num);
//uint sub_group_size = get_sub_group_size();
//printf("in0[%d]: %f\n", global_num, in0[global_num]);
//printf("max sub group size: %d\n", sub_group_size);
//work_group_barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
//barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
printf("global id: %d local id: %d group id: %d num groups %d\n", global_num, local_num, group_id, group_num);
}
```

The funny thing is, the host-side OpenCL 2.0 functions work.  Using clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties returns with a success.  In the older versions of OpenCL, this function existed as clCreateCommandQueue.    CL_DEVICE_VERSION pings back OpenCL 2.0.  I'm running with the AMD Radeon R9 290X 4GB GDDR5, running Ubuntu 14.04, with the latest drivers, and the AMD-APP-SDK 3.0 beta.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by invalid - does it fail to compile or fail to run?

Comment: The whole program compiles, but when executed, the program returns the OpenCL status error.  

I probe the status integer indicators at every step of the host program.  Whenever there is something wrong with the kernel, OpenCL's status indicators will display a message.  In this case, the error message starts off at clBuildProgram, returning "CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_ERROR" when work_group_barrier is uncommented.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to my problem.

clBuildProgram will default to the highest version of OpenCL C compiler 1.X if the option "-cl-std=CL2.0" is not specified in the options portion of the clBuildProgram API call.

The OpenCL C compiler is for the device-side kernel code, and is separate from the Host-side compiliation.  One must manually specify OpenCL 2.0 if they choose to use it.

Comment: only problem now is that there's a segfault when I add the option.